# Best books/sites/blogs to learn DataStructures and Algorithms as a starting level?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Could you please, can any one tell me the best books/sites/blogs to learn DataStructures and Algorithms as a starting level?
in c++ language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For learning data structures and algorithms in general I'd recommend [The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena](http://www.algorist.com/) ([Google books link](http://books.google.ru/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&lpg=PR1&ots=z6eGNRJR1l&dq=algorithm%20design%20manual&pg=PR1#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Answer (score 2):

The definitive book would be [Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937). Try and get a used copy, it's not cheap.

As for sites, the SO tag `data-structures` has some great stuff in it too. You might want to look at the top questions there.